# Swift - Using performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: swift, cocoa, background-process

I'm trying to use `– performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` for a Cocoa application that I'm developing in Swift.  I need the application to wait until the job is done.  Anyway, I have the following lines of code.

```
func recoverData(path:String) -> Void {
    let sheetRect:NSRect = NSMakeRect(0,0,400,114)
    let progSheet:NSWindow = NSWindow.init(contentRect:sheetRect, styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask,backing:NSBackingStoreType.Buffered,`defer`:true)
    let contentView:NSView = NSView.init(frame:sheetRect)
    let progInd:NSProgressIndicator = NSProgressIndicator.init(frame:NSMakeRect(190,74,20,20))
    progInd.style = NSProgressIndicatorStyle.SpinningStyle
    let msgLabel:NSTextField = NSTextField.init(frame:NSMakeRect(20,20,240,46))
    msgLabel.stringValue = "Copying selected file..."
    msgLabel.bezeled = false
    msgLabel.drawsBackground = false
    msgLabel.editable = false
    msgLabel.selectable = false
    contentView.addSubview(msgLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(progInd)
    progSheet.contentView = contentView

    self.window.beginSheet(progSheet) {(NSModalResponse returnCode) -> Void in
        progSheet.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        progInd.startAnimation(self)
        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority,0)) {

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            self.performSelectorOnMainThread(Selector(self.readData(path)),withObject:path,waitUntilDone:true)
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            progInd.indeterminate = true
            self.window.endSheet(progSheet)
            progSheet.orderOut(self)
        }
    }
}

func readData(path:String) -> Void {
    print("Hello!?")
}
```

I'm not sure how I pass `path` to readData.  Xcode requires me to set the argument to something other than nil or nothing.  In Objective-C, it would be

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(readData:) withObject:path waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Anyway, the application never reaches readData.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not

```
self.window.beginSheet(progSheet) {(returnCode) -> Void in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        progInd.startAnimation(self)
        self.readData(path)
        progInd.indeterminate = true
    }
}
```

At some point you have to call `self.window.endSheet(progSheet)` to dismiss the sheet and call the completion handler.

**Edit:**

I guess you actually mean something like this

```
...
  self.window.beginSheet(progSheet) {(returnCode) -> Void in
    progInd.stopAnimation(self)
    progInd.indeterminate = true

  }

  progInd.startAnimation(self)
  let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority,0)) {
    self.readData(path) {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.window.endSheet(progSheet)
      }
    }
  }
}

func readData(path:String, completion: (()  -> Void))  {
  print("Hello!?")
  completion()
}
```

Comment: How would that make the application close the sheet when the job is done?  Besides, the application does not seem to reach readData, anyway.

Comment: Even the first line of your amended code is not valid.

Comment: Right, I edited the answer again. `beginSheet` handles everything, it's not needed to call  `makeKeyAndOrderFront` and `orderOut`

Comment: (1) The application never enters the beginSheet bloc.  (2) Why should I remove performSelectorOnMainThread when in fact I need the application to wait until the background work is done?

Comment: The (completion) block is executed after sending `endSheet(progSheet)` to the window and `performSelectorOnMainThread:method` and `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { method() }` is the same thing in practice.